# Apple iWork / Keynote document fonts warnings (missing, but not used in document)

Tags: fonts, keynote, iwork

I've got a Keynote file which definitely uses only 3 fonts. All 3 fonts are installed in Font Book.

Every time I open the Keynote file, Keynote comes up with a missing fonts warning. I never used these fonts, so was curious. Duplicated my document, deleted ALL slides and master slides apart from one blank white slide, saved document. Reopened the document. Fonts are still missing.

Can anyone please help explain the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue for the past few days. The only solution I could make work:

Export as PowerPoint, reimport, save as Keynote again. Prompt disappeared. Voila.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph styles in the text formatting panel may still be using the fonts. I have resolved a similar issue by creating a slide with type specimens of every paragraph style and updating the styles that had the problem fonts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the type specimens / updating fonts, but it didn't help. The problem is somewhere else...
Hoping that in a future update, Apple will allow users to replace missing fonts (like they used to do with KN09).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the Keynote file *is actually using the font in question*, but that it's just not obvious where it is.  As others have pointed out it is most likely being used in a style definition.  It could also be in another embedded file inside he presentation e.g an `.ai` image file.

One thing you can do to help you narrow down where it's being used is to open a terminal, `cd` to the directory containing the Keynote file & run the following command:

```
font='Corbel';file='a.key';dest=/tmp/`md5 -q $file`;unzip $file -d $dest  &> /dev/null && grep -re $font $dest | cut -c 50- && rm -rf $dest;
```

Replacing `'Calibri'` and `'a.key'` with the name of the font that's missing and the name of the Keynote file respectively.

This will print a list of files inside the Keynote document package (actually a `.zip` file.) where the font name is found.  Most likely this will say there is a match in `Index/DocumentStyleSheet.iwa` (that's your clue that it's the styles that are referencing the font) but it might also reference a master slide or an individual file.

Comment: This answers how to find the place where the font is referenced, but solving the warning is not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to Export to Keynote 09 fix teh font issues and then open in the current version - a real pain but it works. The font issues are often with the master slides.